# How to move objects across layouts using Drag and Drop

Tags: android, layout, drag-and-drop

I can move objects in their parent layout but I could not find how to move them to another layout. Does anyone know it?

Edit: This tutorial shows how to do. [fupeg.blogspot.com/2011/03/honeycomb-drag-and-drop-basics.html](http://fupeg.blogspot.com/2011/03/honeycomb-drag-and-drop-basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a buit-in functionnality coming with Android honeycomb, see [this specific article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).

If you want to do that on earlier versions, try [that tutorial](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html).

Comment: thank you, this tutorial shows how to do. http://fupeg.blogspot.com/2011/03/honeycomb-drag-and-drop-basics.html